# Angular 9: instance of error not working with custom error handler

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, error-handling

I am trying to implement custom error handling using the `ErrorHandler` class in angular

My Globalerror service looks like this

```
export class CustomErrors extends Error {
  button?: any;
  errObject: any;
  constructor() {
    super('custom');
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CustomErrors.prototype);
  }
}
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  // constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
  constructor() {}

  handleError(error: any) {
   
    console.log('custom error', error instanceof CustomErrors);

   }
}
```

In the component, I'm testing

```
ngOnInit() {
    try {
        throw new Error('error on do the thing');
    }
    catch (err) {
        const errs = new CustomErrors();
         //console.log('in service', errs instanceof CustomErrors);
          errs.button = 'Back to the start';
          throw err;
    }
}
```

but the console message in the handlerror function  `console.log('custom error', error instanceof CustomErrors);` always throws `false`

I am not sure why it's not getting true

Comment: Shouldn't `throw err;` be `throw errs;`?

Comment: That was a typo

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with TypeScript
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13965

As a workaround try adding a type on your custom errors like this:

```
export class CustomErrors extends Error {
  button?: any;
  errObject: any;
  get type(): string {
     return "CustomError";
  }
  constructor() {
    super('custom');
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CustomErrors.prototype);
  }
}
```

You can even enforce the `type` member with an interface:

```
export interface AppError {
    type: string;
}
```

and have all of your custom error classes implement it.

Then you can replace `instanceof` with a check for `error.type`

Comment: Getting error duplicate identifier `type`

Comment: Can you please explain the answer a bit?

Comment: Error gone but the `error.type` is undefined

Comment: Maybe that's because of `throw err` instead of `throw errs` ?

Comment: Nope that was a typo actual one throw errs